Dovecot Windows Authentication Remap Alias Domain
I'm planning on setting up a new self-hosted Dovecot e-mail server exposed to the internet with email accounts like david@example.com.
On the other hand, I want to create an internal Windows Active Directory that runs a domain example.corp because I don't want to create a example.com domain and expose it to the internet for security and latency issues.
The goal is that the mail user david@example.com authenticates as david@example.corp having into account that the mail server and the domain server are connected through the local network.
¿Is it possible?
